# mouseleave not working in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

my mouseleave is not working in my jquery code

http://jsfiddle.net/alano/9Dr7T/29/

providing my js code below

```
mouseleave: function () {
    $(this).find("div:last").remove();
}
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior of your `mouseleave` listener and for which element(s)?

Comment: That's a great description for a problem in 200 lines of code ?

Comment: @mmmshuddup: after the add image action...the add image button should not appear any more on mouse hover for that particular img tag...

Comment: @adeneo@mmmshuddup: did u guys get it

Comment: Yes, I got it now.  This is bizarre.

Comment: @mmmshuddup: it works here http://jsfiddle.net/6MmMe/23/ but when i combine my existing carousal its not working

Comment: @user1813724 I find your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't with the `mouseleave` listener, the problem is *how* you're binding those event handlers and *unbinding* them for that matter.  The div was being removed, but it was being readded with every `mouseenter` event.  For some reason the mouseenter event wasn't being unbound when using the **selector** filter for `.on()`.  It probably has something to do with the way [bubbling occurs when using the **selector** filter](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

Now, I'm not 100% sure why just yet, but either way it will work if you use directly-bound handlers like so:

```
$('.specialHover').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $("<div class='cta'>add image</div>").click(function() {
            var $me = $(this);
            $me.parent().unbind('mouseenter').children('img').attr(
                'src', 
                'http://www.onlinegrocerystore.co.uk/images/goodfood.jpg'
            );
            $me.remove();
        }).appendTo(this);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).find('div:last').remove();
    }
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/9Dr7T/35/

Comment: thank u so much....can u give ur skype or gmail id...i did not understand ur explanation...so that i can call u directly pls

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this way:

```
mouseleave: function () {
   $("div:last",this).remove();
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific what it should remove in your fiddle, might be i am not getting it properly.